# Weird rewriterule behaviour

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm hoping someone can help me here. I'm currently trying to make my site more SEO friendly and having some strange issues with .htaccess.

This is all on my testing server. The designer section was working fine without "homeware-designer/" preceding the designer name "cquoi, etc". All good until I added the last one `mage` then it all stopped working, relative links were no longer working properly. I removed  `RewriteRule mage designerdata.php?search=4` and it all started working again. Once I added `homeware-designer/etc` all works fine again???? Can anyone tell me what might be going on. Also some of the rules won't work without `^foo$`, but most will work without the `^$` delimiters and most will not work at all with the ^$ string delimiters. I just need to understand what is going on before I try to put it on the live server.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule designer-homeware index.php  

#------------------ Living ---------------
RewriteRule living-room-hallway category.php?collection=1 

RewriteRule designer-shelves-storage contentdata.php?collection=1&type=17 

RewriteRule designer-cushions-pouffes contentdata.php?collection=1&type=1 

rewriterule designer-coat-hat-racks contentdata.php?collection=1&type=19 

rewriterule designer-lighting contentdata.php?collection=1&type=25 

rewriterule living-room-accessories contentdata.php?collection=1&type=4 

#----------------- Eating ----------------
RewriteRule dining-room-eating category.php?collection=2 

rewriterule designer-tableware contentdata.php?collection=2&type=5 

rewriterule designer-glassware contentdata.php?collection=2&type=6 

rewriterule dining-room-accessories contentdata.php?collection=2&type=8 

#----------------- Bathing ----------------
RewriteRule ^bathroom$ category.php?collection=5 

RewriteRule bathroom-accessories contentdata.php?collection=5&type=11

#----------------- Kids -------------------
RewriteRule ^childrens-decor$ category.php?collection=6 

RewriteRule ^designer-childrens-decor$ contentdata.php?collection=6&type=20 

#----------------- Garden ------------------
RewriteRule garden category.php?collection=7 

RewriteRule garden-accessories contentdata.php?collection=7&type=21

#----------------- Art ---------------------
rewriterule designer-prints contentdata.php?collection=8&type=24 

#----------------- Designers --------------
RewriteRule homeware-designers designer.php

RewriteRule homeware-designer/cquoi designerdata.php?search=7

RewriteRule homeware-designer/remember designerdata.php?search=8

RewriteRule homeware-designer/terafue designerdata.php?search=10

RewriteRule homeware-designer/r-bernier designerdata.php?search=11

RewriteRule homeware-designer/c-l-boym designerdata.php?search=21

RewriteRule homeware-designer/andre-klauser designerdata.php?search=22

RewriteRule homeware-designer/shin-azumi designerdata.php?search=23

RewriteRule homeware-designer/alejandro-ruiz designerdata.php?search=24

RewriteRule homeware-designer/tord-boontje designerdata.php?search=25

RewriteRule homeware-designer/sibo-home-concept designerdata.php?search=13

RewriteRule homeware-designer/zafferano designerdata.php?search=14

RewriteRule homeware-designer/klevering designerdata.php?search=15

RewriteRule homeware-designer/dutch-waaren designerdata.php?search=16

RewriteRule homeware-designer/vintage-casa designerdata.php?search=17

RewriteRule homeware-designer/hubsch-denmark designerdata.php?search=18

RewriteRule homeware-designer/serholt-sweden designerdata.php?search=19

RewriteRule homeware-designer/lazis designerdata.php?search=20

RewriteRule homeware-designer/atlantis designerdata.php?search=26

RewriteRule homeware-designer/mage designerdata.php?search=4
```

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of exact-url rules, it's best to include the `^$` delimiters. The issue with needing the `^$` delimiters is that some rules are subsets of others. For example, the `bathroom` rule would catch the url `bathroom-accessories` if you didn't have the delimiters. In general, if you know that's the entire exact url you want, it's best to have the delimiters.

The other issue is these rules are all being checked, even after they match. In most cases, it isn't a problem, but like the bathroom word, some might be getting matched on more than one rule. To fix this, put `[L]` at the end of the rule, to indicate it's the Last rule if it matches - that is, it says if it matches, be done and exit.

It's common to also include an `NC` flag, for no-case, to not care if it's uppercase or lowercase.

```
RewriteRule designer-homeware index.php [NC,L]

#------------------ Living ---------------
RewriteRule living-room-hallway category.php?collection=1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule designer-shelves-storage contentdata.php?collection=1&type=17 [NC,L]

etc.
```

Try this out and see if it helps. I don't see anything wrong with the mage rule specifically, but the L and delimiters will at least keep the rules from overlapping each other.

Comment: Thanks for the help goodeye, much appreciated, and I will try your recommendations later. Cheers

Comment: Just tried your suggestions about the delimiters, if I use the full url then it works. 
RewriteRule ^living-room-hallway/designer-shelves-storage$ contentdata.php?collection=1&type=17 [NC,L]
Which is now making sense to me. I tried so  many combinations that I probably tried that one but broke it somewhere else - easily done at 3am and your tired and confused.

Comment: Glad this helped. If it did fix everything, please consider accepting and voting my answer. Thanks!